# If WPF BitmapCache is enabled on UserControl the UserControl is invisible on some computers

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapcache

Title says most of it. I have a WPF UserControl that defines the BitmapCache as followed:

```
<UserControl.CacheMode>
    <BitmapCache EnableClearType="False" 
                 RenderAtScale="1" 
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="False"  />
</UserControl.CacheMode>
```

It works on almost all machines like a charm, but one brand new laptop with Intel Iris graphics card. I played around with all kinds of settings, installed a new driver and looked for alternatives. Sadly without this stuff my application - which is full of animations and shadows - runs a lot less smooth.

So i hope i can keep this by fixing the problem somehow. Does someone have a clue for me what i could do on this laptop to correct this error?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could it be just hitting the hardware limits? More likely CPU. You can't make *heavy* wpf application animations looking smooth on all platforms (can be simulated by making CPU cores busy). Add minimum requirements or just tell the user to update his hardware.

Comment: I don't think so. It's a laptop but it's a i7 10th Generation with enough free ram and graphics memory. In the performance overview isn't too much going on, too. There are much weaker desktops in use, that have no problems. 

It also seems to load and there are no crashes or something, because all the elements are there. I see them also by selecting them with hot-reload toolbar. They are just drawn white.

Answer (score 0):

By the moment i submitted this message i found a solution:

If i add this line to my App Startup, everything is working fine:

`RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;`